# Checking progress of MySQL schema change

Tags: mysql, database, schema, database-schema, alter

Is it possible to check the status of a schema change to a MySQL database? i.e. when will `ALTER TABLE myTable DROP INDEX myKey;` complete?

I have dropped a key using PHPMyAdmin for my 1.8 Gb database and PHPMyAdmin is locked up and accessing the command line shows the old schema for `SHOW CREATE TABLE myTable`.

Is it possible to confirm that the `ALTER` is still in progress? Is it possible to estimate when it will complete?

---

See also:

- [Create an index on a huge mysql production table without table locking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244685/create-an-index-on-a-huge-mysql-production-table-without-table-locking) how to make MySQL schema changes on a live server with a master/slave setup running that does not block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's not much you can do to monitor progress of an `ALTER TABLE` statement, nor can we know how much time it has left to finish.

You can use a tool like [pt-online-schema-change](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-online-schema-change.html), which *does* output an estimate of progress and time remaining, but more importantly it **does not block access to the table** while it's working. This is probably why you're concerned with monitoring progress, because it is anxiety-causing to wait for an `ALTER TABLE` to release its lock.

Comment: Forget the lock... I need to know when I can get back to drinking!

Comment: Ah, then pt-online-schema-change will not be something you'd like. It gives progress estimates, but it takes it longer to make an equivalent ALTER TABLE. Salud!

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL 5.7.20 you can monitor progress... see http://ronaldbradford.com/blog/monitoring-an-online-mysql-alter-table-using-performance-schema-2013-11-07/