# Create index in huge MariaDB production database without table locking

Tags: indexing, mariadb, alter-table, table-locking

I have a table with 202M records where I need to add a few indexes and I can't find it anywhere (or maybe I don't understand the lingo) if that is possible to do, without locking, in MariaDB 10.3.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244685/create-an-index-on-a-huge-mysql-production-table-without-table-locking) where I can see that that is possible in MySQL 5.6+, but my google foo didn't get my any info on MariaDB.

I tried using pt-online-schema-change but since I don't have any index (not even primary) that is not an option.

Comment: Which version of MariaDB?  Improvements have been made (out of sync with MySQL).  What, exactly, are the new indexes -- some can be fast, some cannot.

Comment: We are using MariaDB 10.3.17. All indexes are simple indexes (no full-text anything).

Comment: `CREATE INDEX mynewindex ON mytable (thecolumn), ALGORITHM=INPLACE, LOCK=NONE;` that should do.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with the use of [ALTER ONLINE TABLE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-online-ddl-overview/#specifying-an-alter-locking-strategy-using-alter-online-table).

> ALTER ONLINE TABLE is equivalent to LOCK=NONE. Therefore, the ALTER
> ONLINE TABLE statement can be used to ensure that your ALTER TABLE
> operation allows all concurrent DML.

Further reading tells that adding primary keys is a "copy" operation as DB engine needs to copy the whole table to new file, but adding other indexes in an inplace operation.

> InnoDB supports adding a primary key to a table with ALGORITHM set to
> INPLACE. The table is rebuilt, which means that all of the data is
> reorganized substantially, and the indexes are rebuilt. As a result,
> the operation is quite expensive. This operation supports the
> non-locking strategy. This strategy can be explicitly chosen by
> setting the LOCK clause to NONE. When this strategy is used, all
> concurrent DML is permitted.
>
> InnoDB supports adding a plain index to a table with ALGORITHM set to
> INPLACE. The table is not rebuilt. This operation supports the
> non-locking strategy. This strategy can be explicitly chosen by
> setting the LOCK clause to NONE. When this strategy is used, all
> concurrent DML is permitted.

More info in [MariaDB documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-online-ddl-operations-with-the-inplace-alter-algorithm/#alter-table-add-primary-key).